# Web Server Setup

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, web-server

In my workplace, we want to implement your own web server for at leat 100 Apache/PHP/MySQL web pages.

My boss is opposed to hiring skilled personnel, he think we can do ourselves.

Currently, we are working with hostgator reseller account.

I chose CentOS as the operating system, but I don't know the best hardware solution.

HP, Dell ? What about the setup on these platforms?

Thanks.

PS: sorry for my bad english

Edit: The purpose of this migration isn't related to performance issues. But independence.

Comment: I think your requirements are too vague for anyone to give a proper answer.

Comment: @mr-euro, sorry but that is the way it is for me. I googled a lot, before posting here.

Comment: I am saying that you may need to add more details to your question about what type of sites (traffic, load, etc) before anyone can tell you you need y, x or z hardware.

Comment: right, this is the picture: about 100 sites with a aprox month transfer of 30GB, according to the actual server, it says it's 40-50% loaded.. (shared hosting) my sites are standar business sites.

Comment: I presume your boss won't listen to this, but my opinion would be that you should stay with your current hosting solution (and maybe look for a different company to work for). Providers of hosted services take the pain of day-to-day server admin away from people like you. And most of them probably provide a better up-time record than you can, plus they don't really care (too much) what is hosted on these sites. I cannot really see what your boss is trying to achieve he could not get in the current line-up.

Comment: wolfgangsz, the goal is to expand capabilities in the future, and the most important he mentioned: interact with the server locally. And of course save money (the last one I don't know if will be true)

Comment: I've been chatting with HP sales assesor, and he recommends me the Proliant ML370.. it this a good option?

Comment: How many visitors are you seeing per day?  How much bandwidth are you using per day?  How large is your database?  How much disk space do your sites require?  How much memory is your current system using?  How much of your current CPU is your current system using?  These are just a few questions you are going to have to answer if you want any useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your really going to have to look at your requirements, are you planning on having your DBs separate from your web servers or will this be very thrifty and your throwing everything on one machine? I'd side with wolfgangsz on this one. This could turn into a headache if you don't have your requirements ironed out well..